# Image Upload Preview File Path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm following the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded) to create a file upload with image preview.

I have it working, but can't figure out how to place the file path in a separate div. Here's the js:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('[data-label="UploadPreview"]').children('img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$('#UploadInput').change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

This is the element where I want to place the file path text:

```
<div data-label="UploadPath"></div>
```

I have tried setting `.text` on the `reader.onload` function as such

```
$('[data-label="UploadPath"]').text(e.target.result);
```

But the result appears to be the base64 value of the image. Can you help me figure out how to include the path of the image in the `data-label="UploadPath"` div? Thanks for your ideas! BTW, I'm new to jQuery so an example of how to include in my current code would help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have that written you're trying to target an `img` tag as a child of the `data-label=UploadPath`, so if you put in an empty `<img/>` then the script can append the image like so:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nA66G/2/)

You can also append an `<img/>` tag instead of leaving a blank one in there, your choice

UPDATE:

Just grab the value when uploading, you can use regex to strip out the path before the filename if needed

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nA66G/2/)

**UPDATE AGAIN** I stripped out the path so you just get the file name:

[UPDATED FIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/nA66G/4/)

Comment: No i mean I want to style the text that says where the path is located on the filesystem. So I want to put the text in a separate div: `div data-label="UploadPath"`. Does that make more sense? I have the upload preview working fine, I just want to put the text that says the path somewhere else..